# tcolorbox, tabularx: first line with a multicolumn does not work in tcolorbox environment

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I have a problem with `tabularx` in a `tcolorbox` environment, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{i}{>{\hsize=.005\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.15\hsize}X}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!0.8!white,colframe=black!4!white,
colbacktitle=gray!40!white, coltitle=black,width=1.0\linewidth,tabularx={ibs}]   
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{ibs}   
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\vspace{3cm}

\end{document}
```

In a regular `tabularx` environment, the table is okay (see 2nd table). However, if I do the same in a `tcolorbox` environment (1st table), the first line, which contains a `multicolumn`, does not work, whereas the other 5 show up, if one passes all the errors.

[image]

The error is (appears 6x):

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.31 \end{tcolorbox}

?
```

I tried to play with the 'size' of the first multicolumn but did not succeed.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: unrelated to the error but your `ibs` heading is wrong , you have 3 X columns so the total width should be 3\hsize and 1+.005+.15 is not 3, tabularx will most likely fail to converge to sensible size given that input.

Comment: David: If I use  2.845+.005+.15 = 3, everything is put to the left of the table.

Comment: I do not know your intended design but any output made by tabularx given widths of 1+.005+.15 is entirely accidental , there is only one rule in the tabularx documentation and that is, don't do that:-)

Comment: I agree since I found your example below ... . Sorry, I couldn't wait. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to just put the `\multicolumn` in the second row, leaving an empty first row that you can back up with a negative vspace. I also fixed your `ibs` definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=2.8\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{i}{>{\hsize=.05\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.15\hsize}X}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\errorcontextlines400
\tracingonline2

%\tracingall
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!0.8!white,colframe=black!4!white,
colbacktitle=gray!40!white, coltitle=black,width=1.0\linewidth,tabularx={ibs}]%
\\
\noalign{\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip}}
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}
                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{ibs}   
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\vspace{3cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot, it works! Q: Why must one insert first an empty row? Is that due to a 'bug'?

Comment: @Krumpel `\multicolumn` has to be the first thing in the cell otherwise the cell template gets added and it is too late to substitute the spanning information. even invisible stuff like `relax` or `{}` is enough to break it. So somewhere in the many  lines of tcolorbox keyval processing it is is constructing a call to tabularx with `{}` or `\relax` or something:-) after the `{ibs}` argument.  I could spend a day tracing where but it's easier to write off that row and start again on the next row:-) (it may be worth giving the tcolorbox author a link to this, would be easier for him to trace)

Comment: @Krumpel This is a tcolorbox bug, which has been [reported today](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/60). By the moment, Thomas F. Sturm has provided a provisional hack to solve the problem. You can see how to use it in the update section of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475797/1952)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved with `tcolorbox v4.20`. Now, `multicolumn` option can be used in top most row without problems.

OP's code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{i}{>{\hsize=.005\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.15\hsize}X}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!0.8!white,colframe=black!4!white,
colbacktitle=gray!40!white, coltitle=black,width=1.0\linewidth,tabularx={ibs}]   
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\vspace{3cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{ibs}   
    \multicolumn{2}{b}{Number}                           & 11     \\\hline                  
    & part a                                             & 38     \\\hline 
    & part b                                             & 4      \\\hline 
    & part c                                             & 2      \\\hline\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 217    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 2}                         & 20     \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 105    \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 3100   \\\hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Blabla 1}                         & 367\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\vspace{3cm}

\end{document}
```

produces the expected result without any error message

[image]