# Tcolorbox :: sidebyside option gives poor result

Tags: tcolorbox

sidebyside option gives poor result...

**without sidebyside, code works well.**

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{linen}{HTML}{FAF0E6}

\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96, 0.64, 0.38}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Formulas,
%sidebyside,
enhanced,
colback=linen,
colframe=sandybrown,
coltext=DarkRed,
coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
fontupper=\noindent,
segmentation style={dashed, red},
segmentation code={
\path[color=red,draw]
(segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
]
Some Text \bfseries{Some text}
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\tcbline
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\tcbline
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
%
\tcblower
Some Text \bfseries{Some text}
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\tcbline
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\tcbline
\begin{equation*}
a = b + c
\end{equation*}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**WITHOUT sidebyside...**
[image: OUTPUT]

**WITH sidebyside...**
[image]

Answer (score 6):

In this case, why not use just a `tabularx` inside the `tcolorbox`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table, usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96,0.64,0.38}
\definecolor{linen}{HTML}{FAF0E6}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\rowcolors{1}{linen}{linen!70!DarkRed}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=linen, colframe=sandybrown,
    title=Formulas, coltitle=white, fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
    clip upper, fontupper=\sffamily,%
    coltext=DarkRed,
    tabularx*={\arrayrulecolor{DarkRed}}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|%
              >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}]

Some Text \bfseries{Some text} & 
Some Text \bfseries{Some text} \\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update:

OP images show a left aligned text on first line. In my original answer I couldn't reproduce this behaviour due to a problem when a `\multicolumn` command is introduced in first cell of a tabularx tcolorbox. This problem is shown in [tcolorbox, tabularx: first line with a multicolumn does not work in tcolorbox environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351170/tcolorbox-tabularx-first-line-with-a-multicolumn-does-not-work-in-tcolorbox-en). Now, thank you to Thomas F. Sturm (`tcolorbox` author) there's a provisional solution for this problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table, usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96,0.64,0.38}
\definecolor{linen}{HTML}{FAF0E6}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
    hackfortabularx/.code={%
        \def\tcb@saveupperbox{%
            \begin{tcb@savebox}{\tcb@upperbox}{\tcb@w@upper}
                \kvtcb@fontupper\kvtcb@halignupper\kvtcb@before@upper}}
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=linen, colframe=sandybrown,
    title=Formulas, coltitle=white, fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
    clip upper, hackfortabularx,
   fontupper=\sffamily, coltext=DarkRed,
   tabularx*={\rowcolors{1}{linen}{linen!70!DarkRed}\arrayrulecolor{DarkRed}}%
        {>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}]

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Some Text \bfseries{Some text}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Some Text \bfseries{Some text}} \\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2nd update:

The problem with `multicolumn` command on left column of top most rule has been solved in `tcolorbox v4.20`. There's no need for previous pacth. Seond figure can be obtained with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table, usenames, dvipsnames, svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96,0.64,0.38}
\definecolor{linen}{HTML}{FAF0E6}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, colback=linen, colframe=sandybrown,
    title=Formulas, coltitle=white, fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
    clip upper, 
   fontupper=\sffamily, coltext=DarkRed,
   tabularx*={\rowcolors{1}{linen}{linen!70!DarkRed}\arrayrulecolor{DarkRed}}%
        {>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}]

\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Some Text \bfseries{Some text}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Some Text \bfseries{Some text}} \\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$\\\hline
$a= b+c$ & $a= b+c$
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem arises because the `sidebyside` option appears to modify the segmentation node so that `\tcblower` can produce a vertical line between the two units instead of the usual horizontal one. Consequently, `\tcbline` does not work as expected, since it uses the same segmentation code which relies on the segmentation node.

I can't find any examples in the package documentation of using `\tcbline` with the `sidebyside` option, so it is not clear doing so is supported.

You can get a box reasonably close to your intended result with a solid, vertical line by setting your segmentation style to solid (red) and removing the segmentation code (Which is causing problems). Dashed horizontal lines are not present, however.

The changes

```
segmentation style={solid, red}
% segmentation code={
% \path[color=red,draw]
% (segmentation.west) -- (segmentation.east);}
```

produces

[image: output]

The only workaround I can see is to manually draw the segmentation lines using the `overlay` option (disabling the in-built ones with the `segmentation hidden` key). You can do this somewhat pragmatically using the `frame` node and the tikizlibrary `calc` library:

```
% \usetikzlibrary{calc} % Preamble
% Box options
[title=Formulas,
sidebyside,
enhanced,
colback=linen,
colframe=sandybrown,
coltext=DarkRed,
coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\small\bfseries,
fontupper=\noindent,
segmentation hidden, % Hide the inbuilt segmentation - we're drawing our own
overlay={
\coordinate (FL) at (frame.west);
\coordinate (FT) at (frame.north);
\coordinate (FR) at (frame.east);
\coordinate (FB) at (frame.south);
\coordinate (L1) at (frame.center);  % Center of frame is about right height
\coordinate (L2) at (0,1.1); % Second dashed line at height of 1.1
\def\borderthickness{2} % Offset due to borders of box
\def\titlethickness{15} % Offset due to box title
\draw [red,dashed] let  \p{FT}=(FT),\p{FB}=(FB) in (\x{FB},\y{FB}+\borderthickness) -- (\x{FT},\y{FT}-\titlethickness);
\draw [red,dashed] let  \p{FR}=(FR),\p{FL}=(FL),\p{L1}=(L1) in (\x{FL}+\borderthickness,\y{L1}) -- (\x{FR}-\borderthickness,\y{L1});
\draw [red,dashed] let  \p{FR}=(FR),\p{FL}=(FL),\p{L2}=(L2) in (\x{FL}+\borderthickness,\y{L2}) -- (\x{FR}-\borderthickness,\y{L2});
}
]
```

For use of `let` in `\draw` commands, see, for example, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63569/172926). When constructing future boxes, you should hopefully only have to edit the coordinates `L1` and `L2` to get the height of the horizontal lines correct (note that only the y-component of these coordinates is used).

Output:

[image: output2]